# How to find $\langle Z_1...Z_{N-1} \rangle$ knowing $\langle Z_1...Z_{N} \rangle$ and $\langle Z_i \rangle$

Tags: measurement, quantum-circuit

I have a quantum circuit with $N$ qubits represented by the unitary $U$. The initial state is $| 00...0\rangle$ and $\psi=U|00...0\rangle$.

Given $\langle\psi| Z_1...Z_{N} |\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi|Z_i |\psi\rangle$ $\forall i$, is there a way to find the expectation value $\langle \psi|Z_1...Z_{N-1} |\psi\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general, no.

Consider the state
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0x\rangle+|1\bar x\rangle\right)|+\rangle
$$
for $x\in\{0,1\}$. We have $\langle Z_i\rangle=0$, and $\langle Z_1Z_2Z_3\rangle=0$ (to see this most trivially, look at the third qubit). However, the first two qubits are an eigenstate of $Z_1Z_2$ of eigenvalue $(-1)^x$. From the values you have (which do not depend on $x$) you cannot get the result for the two-qubit observable because it depends on $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

2 assumptions for my answer (because I did not really understood your setup):

- Let's assume a pure state like |0010110> (not superposition)
- Assume you are doing the same experiment again and again (because in each time you collapse and project your state)

The N Zs operator is actually counting if there is an odd or even number of ones in the state.

Using all Zi, you can also know exactly which of them was 0 and which is 1. (and you don't need the

So sure you can know the (N-1) Zs expectation value. (even without the N Zs measure)

In the case of superposition, the expectation value is probabilistic. So you can't say you know it.

Comment: Yes I can't say I know it in a superposition state. I supposed that I'm in a perfect classical simulator, so I can actually know every expectation value I need. I was not clear in the question, sorry. Thank you for the reply, @DaftWullie told me what i wanted to know!